# Netbeans:get the X and Y co ordinate

Tags: netbeans-7

I have an image in the jlabel. I want to get the X and Y co-ordinate when ever it is clicked on. I used the following code:

```
private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    f = jLabel2.getMousePosition();
    m = new Point(f).toString();
}
```

And I got the output:

```
java.awt.Point[x=165,y=105]
```

But I don't know how take the x and y separately.

Comment: Please, when you type your answer please make sure that your code is well written and indented inside the code tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point class two public fields which are x and y. You can access them through your instance variable.

You do the following. int x1 = m.x; int y1 = m.y.

if you need extra information and some useful methods, read the Java Api.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html